# PHP exec returns correctly for some commands using sudo, not others

Tags: php, asterisk

I'm getting successful output when I issue the following in a PHP script:

```
$peers_summary = exec('sudo asterisk -x "sip show peers"', $sip_peers);
```

`$sip_peers` contains the full output of the exec command, listing the peers in standard table format that Asterisk provides. However, when I issue:

```
$test = exec('sudo asterisk -x "sip show peer trunk-to-pbx"', $trunk);
```

`$trunk` is completely empty: `array(0) {}`, and
`$test` is an empty string: `string(0) ""`

`trunk-to-pbx` is a valid peer in my Asterisk installation, and I've verified that issuing `sudo asterisk -x "sip show peer trunk-to-pbx"` at the prompt is successful (as is `sudo asterisk -x "sip show peers"`), so I'm not sure why the second command returns empty from `exec()`. I thought initially that it might be an output character limit, but the output has less than 2,000 characters - couldn't be a memory or limit issue. I tried `set_time_limit(0)` even though the execution is virtually instantaneous at the prompt.

Why is the second `exec()` returning empty?

Comment: What is the value of $test?

Comment: Thanks for responding. `$test` is also empty, when it should the last line of the output.

Comment: Might be worth adding a third parameter to exec(), and inspecting what that value is.

Comment: Returns `1`, which I believe indicates successful execution..? 

EDIT: NOPE - something is wrong, I get `0` in the third parameter when added to the first command...so it looks like `exec()` doesn't like something in the second version...hhmm..

Comment: Also, if you could be specific about what the return value is. 'empty' is not a type. The more information the better.

Comment: More specific info, with `var_dump()`:

`$test: string(0) ""

$trunk: array(0) {
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with `exec()`, or `asterisk`, or the command I was passing to `exec()`; there's a `sudoers` file that whitelists commands, and my command needed inclusion before the `exec()` would work. Inherited codebase. Thanks **Chris Stryczynski**, for your suggestions.